# Copy Specific folder from one location to another Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to copy a specific folder from one location to another. I want the entire folder to be copied not just the contents of the folder.

I have tried as:

```
shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=True)
```

But this copies the content of the folder, not the entire folder.

Comment: Just let the `dst` to be contain the directory name of  `src` like `shutil.copytree('a/b/c/G', 'b/t/y/G', symlinks=True)`

Comment: make sure to do a check if the folder name all ready exists or you'll see FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'b/t/y/G'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
shutil.copytree(src, os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src)), symlinks=True)
```

Some might disagree with this approach. but it does exactly what you need here.